# jQuery touchend event issue blocking (using Cordova)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, touch

I used a listener on mousedown and mouseup to react differently if it was going from one canvas to one another. On website, perfect. But it must be mobile, so to make it work I went with touchstart and touchend event.

And it doesn't work as expected.

Here are some code :

HTML (it is simply a left side canvas and right side canvas)

```
<canvas class="left" style="position: relative; background-color: #FFF; width: 45%; height: 80px;"></canvas><canvas class="right" style="position: relative; background-color: #FFF; width: 45%; height: 80px;"></canvas>
```

JS

```
$('canvas').on("touchstart", function(e) { //mousedown for mobile
    console.log('CONSOLE: start ' + this.className);
    down = this;
});
$('canvas').on("touchend", function(e) { //mouseup for mobile
    console.log('CONSOLE: end ' + this.className);
    calc(down, this);
});
function calc(press, depress) {
    code...
}
```

I used ADB Logcat to debug and here is the unexpected behaviour.

```
I/chromium(28808): [INFO:CONSOLE(148)] "CONSOLE: Reinitialized", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/share.js (148)
I/chromium(28808): [INFO:CONSOLE(21)] "CONSOLE: start left", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/share.js (21)
I/chromium(28808): [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "CONSOLE: end left", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/share.js (25)
I/chromium(28808): [INFO:CONSOLE(21)] "CONSOLE: start left", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/share.js (21)
I/chromium(28808): [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "CONSOLE: end left", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/share.js (25)
I/chromium(28808): [INFO:CONSOLE(21)] "CONSOLE: start right", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/share.js (21)
I/chromium(28808): [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "CONSOLE: end right", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/share.js (25)
I/chromium(28808): [INFO:CONSOLE(21)] "CONSOLE: start right", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/share.js (21)
I/chromium(28808): [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "CONSOLE: end right", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/share.js (25)
```

So what did I do for this.

Reinitialized is simply a reset to clean stage.

The first two lines "start left end left" is simply a tap in the left side canvas.

Then, the next two lines are "start left end left" too. BUT here, I slided from left canvas to right canvas, without getting the expected "start left end right". Same goes for right.

I also use Cordova (for hybrid HTML5 apps) on a Android 5.0 Lollipop Moto G (2nd Gen) phone.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected this issue by using touchmove event with elementFromPoint()